# Searching Multiple Models Simultaneously in Sunspot/Solr for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, solr, sunspot

Simple question, How do I search multiple models using Sunspot?...I'm using Sunspot with Rails, and I can't seem to find how I search across multiple models. Do I need to create a separate controller or can I use the Gear Controller with the index action?

Thanks for the help.

(side note: I found a question on stackoverflow very similar to this but they didn't post their code..so I apologize for any redundancy.)

I have the following in my view:

```
<div class="side_bar_search">
    <%= form_tag gears_path, :method => :get do %>
      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

and the following models

**Gear**

```
class Gear < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :size, :price, :sub_category_id, :user_id, :image, :image_a, :remote_image_url
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :sub_category
  has_one :category, :through => :sub_category
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy 
  require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
  mount_uploader :image, GearpicUploader
  mount_uploader :image_a, GearpicUploader


  searchable do
    text :title, :size, :price #need to add sub-category, and User Name.  
  end...
```

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :userimage, :remove_userimage
  has_secure_password
  has_many :gears
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy 
  has_one :store, :dependent => :destroy
  before_save :create_remember_token
  require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
  mount_uploader :userimage, UserpicUploader

   searchable do
     text :first_name, :last_name
   end...
```

**Gears Controller**

```
class GearsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = Gear.search do
        fulltext params[:search]
        paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

    @gears = @search.results
  end...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Sunspot.search [Gear, User] do
  ....
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately if you're paginating and there are enough results in Gear, it won't return any User objects.  I'd been hoping it'd get both results and sort by relevancy.

Comment: @Kevin, would you be able to get around this (sort of) by ordering by creation date to get a mixed list of Gear and User?

Comment: when doing fulltext search you can sort the results by score using order_by(:score, :desc)

Comment: in which file should this code live? how do i tell Sunspot to index this?

Answer (score 0):

Also, a gem that can be handy for this is

https://github.com/toptierlabs/acts_as_fulltextable

It doesn't have any dependency with the search server.